# Update a list if there is any matching item

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I write below code in streams? `topics` is an `ArrayList<Topic>`.

```
public void updateTopic(Topic topic) {
    for (int i = 0; i < topics.size(); i++) {
        Topic t = topics.get(i);
        if (t.getId().equals(topic.getId())) {
            topics.set(i, topic);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something? You'll learn way faster if you do.

Comment: Based on your logic, you might want to use a `Map<String,Topic>` instead of `List<Topic>`. Then your entire code can be replaced by `topics.replace(topic.getId(),topic);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Intstream` by importing it as follows

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
```

```java
public void updateTopic(Topic topic) {
    IntStream.range(0, topics.size())
            .filter(i -> topics.get(i).getId().equals(topic.getId()))
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(i -> topics.set(i, topic));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `Stream::map`? Map to the same object unless the ID are equal - then map to the new one. This can be achieved simply using the ternary operator.

```
public void updateTopic(Topic topic) {
    topics = topics.stream()
        .map(t -> t.getId().equals(topic.getId()) ? topic : t)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```